# How I can add a custom error key in Devise custom authentication strategy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

It is necessary to make so that the authorization errors in the Devise worked in the same way as the ActiveModel::Errors in RubyOnRails, i.e. The error was available in the hash by the key corresponding to the field name.

I want to get response from server like this `{ errors: { user:  'User not found' } }` or `{errors: { password: 'Invalid password' } }`, but I still get  `{ error: 'User not found' }` from server.

My custom strategy:

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class Password < Authenticatable

      def authenticate!
        resource  = password.present? && mapping.to.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_hash)

        if resource
          if validate(resource){ resource.valid_password?(password) }
            remember_me(resource)
            resource.after_database_authentication
            success!(resource)
          else
            errors.add(:password, I18n.t('devise.failure.invalid_password'))
            fail!(:invalid_password)
          end
        else
          errors.add(:user, I18n.t('devise.failure.user_not_found'))
          fail!(:user_not_found)
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to modify config/locales/devise.en.yml but you must add the settings, they are not there by default.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But you do not quite understand my question. The problem is not in the translation of the errors, but in the answer format of the method `Devise::Strategies::DatabaseAuthenticatable#authenticate!`